# To what extent can I change an AGPL project?

Tags: agpl

Is it legal to fork an AGPL project and change names and namespaces? All the work will be public and available to users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AGPL license allows you to change anything and everything within the project, except

- the license. The modified project must remain under the AGPL license
- the copyright lines. You are not allowed to remove or modify existing copyright lines -- except when completely removing a file; no need to keep a file that consists only of copyright information --, but you can add your own copyright line.

Comment: sorry for asking too much.
I am trying to rebrand the AGPL project into a new project with some additional features.
while keeping all the work public. Is that legit?

Comment: @maherbta, yes that is legit.